# how to make comma-delimited txt file using streamwriter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

It is writing to txt file file but only 1 field per line. I need a comma between each field in the text file so each record is on 1 line. How do I do that?

Here's this portion of my code.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class ContactInfoForm
' Declare module-level variable.
Private ContactInfoStreamWriter As StreamWriter

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    ' Save the users contact information to the end of the file.

    ' Make sure name field and at least 1 number field is not empty.
    If NameTextBox.Text <> "" And PhoneNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Or PagerNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Or
        CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Or VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text <> "" Then

        If ContactInfoStreamWriter IsNot Nothing Then ' Check if the file is open
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(NameTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(PagerNumberTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(EmailAddressTextBox.Text)

            With NameTextBox
                .Clear()
                .Focus()
            End With
            PhoneNumberTextBox.Clear()
            PagerNumberTextBox.Clear()
            CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Clear()
            VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Clear()
            EmailAddressTextBox.Clear()
        Else        ' File is not open
            MessageBox.Show("You must open the file before you can save your contact information.", "File is Not Open",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            ' Display the File Open dialog box.
            OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e)
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name and at least 1 number where you can be reached.", "Data Entry Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        NameTextBox.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not keep a file open for the lifetime of your application. It is an useless waste of resources and your user should not be concerned with this problems. Open it yourself when you need it and close afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're using WriteLine where it writes its parameter into a single line.  You can either use .Write()  or use String.Format(), example:

```
Dim info As String = ""
            info = String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", _
            NameTextBox.Text, PhoneNumberTextBox.Text, PagerNumberTextBox.Text, CellPhoneNumberTextBox.Text, VoiceMailNumberTextBox.Text, EmailAddressTextBox.Text)
            ContactInfoStreamWriter.WriteLine(info)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much zhack!